# how to connect to mariadb when both mysql and mariadb exist in the remote server

Tags: mysql, mariadb, remote-connection

I'm trying to connect to mariadb in the remote server, I've got both mysql and mariadb installed in the server. Now when I try to connect to mariadb using the following parameters, instead of mariadb I'm connected to mysql. Any suggestion on how to solve this.

```
mysql -h <host_ip> -uroot -p --socket=user@<host_ip>:/opt/mariadb-data/mariadb.sock
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-P` argument to specify the port that the MariaDB server is running on.

```
mysql ... -P <port> ...
```

Comment: yeah thanks that did it. Don't know why I didn't try it